# Python+Postgresql: Ideal way to call data for computation (rolling / expanding window) + multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a huge database (~100 variables with a few million rows) consisting of stock data. I managed to connect python with the database via sqlalchemy (postgreql+psycopg2). I am running it all on the cloud.

In principle I want to do a few things: 
1) Regression of all possible combinations: I am running a simple regression of each stock, i.e. ABC on XYZ AND also XYZ on ABC, this across the n=100 stocks, resulting in n(n+1) / 2 combinations.
-> I think of a function that calls in the pairs of stocks, does the two regressions and compares the results and picks one based on some criteria.
My question: Is there an efficient way to call in the "factorial"?

2) Rolling Windows: To avoid an overload of data, I thought to only call the dataframe of investigation, i.e. 30days, and then roll over each day, meaning my periods are:

```
 1: 1D-30D
 2: 2D-31D and so on
```

Meaning I always drop the first day and add another row at the end of my dataframe. So meaning I have two steps, drop the first day and read in the next row from my database. 
My question: Is this a meaningful way or does Python has something better in its sleeve? How would you do it?

3) Expanding windows: Instead of dropping the first row and add another one, I keep the 30 days and add another 30days and then run my regression. Problem here, at some point I would embrace all the data which will probably be too big for the memory?
My question: What would be a workaround here?

4) As I am running my analysis on the cloud (with a few more cores than my own pc) in fact I could use multithreading, sending "batch" jobs and let Python do things in parallel. I thought of splitting my dataset in 4x 25 stocks and let it run in parallel (so vertical split), or should I better split horizontally?
Additionally I am using Jupyter; I am wondering how to best approach here, usually I have a shell script calling my_program.py. Is this the same here?

Comment: `~100 variables with a few million rows` You are probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to give answers categorically and also note my observations.

1. From your description, I suppose you have taken each stock scrip as one variable and you are trying to perform pairwaise linear regression amongst them. Good news about this - it's highly parallizable. All you need to do is generate unique combinations of all possible pairings and perform your regressions and then only to keep those models which fit your criteria.
2. Now as stocks are your variables, I am assuming rows are their prices or something similar values but definitely some time series data. If my assumption is correct then there is a problem in rolling window approach. In creating these rolling windows what you are implicitly doing is using a data sampling method called '[bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics))' which uses random but repeatitive sampling. But due to just rolling your data you are not using random sampling which might create problems for your regression results. At best the model may simply be overtrained, at worst, I cannot imagine. Hence, drop this appraoch. Plus if it's a time series data then the entire concept of windowing would be questionable anyway.
3. Expanding windows are no good for the same reasons stated above.
4. About memory and processibility -  I think this is an excellent scenario where one can use [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/). It is exactly built for this purpose and has excellent support for python. Millions of data points are no big deal for Spark. Plus, you would be able to massively parallelize your operations. Being on cloud infrastructure also gives you advantage about configurability and expandability without headache. I don't know why people like to use Jupyter even for batch tasks like these but if you are hell-bent on using it, then PySpark kernel is also supported by Jupyter. Vertical split would be right approach here probably.

Hope these answer your questions.

Comment: Dear Chadwick, thank you very much for your answer: 1. yes, that's what I want to do. 2. It is some kind of backtesting; imagine you take the last 30 days to find some relationship and then tomorrow you start doing sth with it, pretending that you get in some data points at specific frequency. But of course overfitting is an issue. 4. So I assume (cant click the link somehow) it's not the spark module in Python but Apache Spark itself, ie abstract from postgres and migrate to AS? I am not focusing on Jupyter, anythin else is fine also (just never used anything else, besides RStudio and Matlab)

Comment: @eternity1 Looks like standard time series models (ARIMA family) will be better suited for such task then, but you know the use case better. As for Apache Spark, yes you will have to use Spark runtime and PySpark SDK. Spark can connect to any database and read data parallelly.. Could you please also mark the answer if it has helped you?